# Minecraft Corrupted and i cant play anymore, how can i fix this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When i try to start my launcher, it tells me that the system is corrupted and it can't find the path specified. What do you do?

Comment: Please post the error report/logs that you get. We need more information to fix your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your installation is corrupted and you need to reinstall Minecraft. Go to the %appdata%.minecraft folder and delete that. If you want to keep your saves, **back them up** first.

To access this folder on Windows, hold down the windows key and press r to open the run menu. Type %appdata% into that.

When you start Minecraft, it will download it again. Let it download, put your saves back and hopefully it'll work.